# How would I normailze the data for a scheduling system using months?

Tags: database, database-design

I am a student working for a non-profit organization that wants a web platform for a scheduling system and a MYSQL database. I don't know much about databasing, but I am learning. The scheduling works as follows: volunteers schedule their shift(s) for the next month (and if possible the month after next). Currently, we have 6 tables: Users, LastMonth, CurrentMonth, NextMonth, MonthAfterNext, and ShiftProposals.

- Users have the following: UserID (this is the primary key), First ame, LastName, Email, Hash, Salt, SkillLevel, and (dates like training, InHouse, etc)
- LastMonth/CurrentMonth/NextMonth/MonthAfterNext have the same following keys: Day (the primary key), UserID, and Shift (4 shifts a day, so it's 1-4).
- ShiftProposals contains all the proposals for CurrentMonth that would need to go through the scheduling algorithm before being placed into the generated schedule.

The issue is in the four schedules. In the database they are formatted in way how we view calendar months. Each volunteer can work 1 to 5 shifts a month. Shift proposals roll over from the previous month, unless scheduled otherwise.

Should we consolidate the 4 months worth of tables into 1? If we do make them 1 table, what would the Primary Key be? What happens when volunteers have multiple shifts per month?

Comment: What is Day in the Month tables?  Is it 13 for the 13th of the month, or is it 1 - 7 or 0 - 6 for the day of the week?

Comment: Day is an integer representing the day of the month. For example if Day = 13, then yes it would be the 13th of the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a database, it's a good idea to have blind keys.  For example, I would change the User table to:

```
User
----
User Number
User ID
Last Name
First Name
Email
Password Hash
Skill Level
...
```

The idea is that everything that has to do with a User, and only a User is in this table.  User Number is an auto-incrementing integer that will be used as part of the key to tables relating to the user.  User ID should be a unique index, but not the primary key.  That way, if you need to change the User ID for a user, you change it in one place.  No one sees or knows what the User Number is for a user.  The User Number is **only** used to tie database tables together.

The password salt should not be stored as a column in the database named salt.  You're giving away half of the key to the password hash. It ought to be something like the Last Name concatenated with the User ID.

You mention multiple dates like training and in-house.  Whenever you have a multiple of something, you create a separate table.  You didn't provide enough information for me to give this table a good, descriptive name.

```
Training
--------
Training Number
User Number
Training Type (In-house, Outside, etc.)
Training Date
```

Training Number is an auto-incrementing integer.  User Number is a foreign key back to the User table.

Yes, you could make Shift one table.  You could also have Shift and ShiftProposals as two tables.  Here's Shift as one table.

```
Shift
-----
Shift Number
User Number
Shift Time Stamp
Shift Code (1 - 4)
Shift Length
Proposed Boolean
```

Shift Number is an auto-incrementing integer.  User Number is a foreign key.

Shift Time Stamp is a time stamp giving the full calendar date of the shift and a time component indicating the start of the shift.  This column, along with the Shift Length column, gives you the flexibility to create half shifts or even quarter shifts.  Otherwise, the columns document when a shift starts and ends.  The User Number, Shift Time Stamp (descending), and Shift Length make another unique index.

The Proposed Boolean marks whether a shift is proposed (true) or not (false).  If you create two tables, this boolean is not needed.

I hope this is enough to get you started.  When you create a relational database, you define the relations.  This is called [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I have some followup questions. For the Password Hash under the User table, do you mean I add the salt with the hash? Where hash("hello") = 4ae25 and salt = 68bbd, the Password Hash = 4ae2568bbd. I just concatenate the salt onto the end of the hashed password, of course these are examples.

Comment: Also, yes the training would include different training type dates, like the In-house, FamilyCounseling, ChildrenCounseling, etc. And Finally for the Shift table. I have a separate table ShiftKey which has the following:Shift (1-4), DateEnacted, StartOfShift, and EndOfShift. How would I connect this ShiftKey table to the Shift table? The purpose for the ShiftKey table is so the admin can change the hard set shift times and number of shifts in a day.

Comment: Sorry for another followup. With the ShiftTable consolidating 4 months worth of schedules, is there more to normalize the data or am I over thinking? The website shows the LastMonth's schedule, which is already complete, and the CurrentMonth, which is already completed with the generated schedule. However, NextMonth and MonthAfterNext are yet to be generated, but volunteers can see which shift proposals are full. These monthly tables are cycled, like if the current month is April, then LastMonth = March. If the current month is May, then LastMonth = April. That's how it works.

Comment: @user3920645: When you hash a password, you concatenate the characters of the salt and the password, then you perform the hash.  In your example, you hash("hellopassword").  Or, as I suggested, hash("lastnamepassworduserid").  You didn't mention the ShiftKey table before.  I included the contents of the ShiftKey table in the Shift table.  The Shift Code is no longer needed.  The Shift table data is already normalized.  You might need another unique index on Shift Time Stamp (descending), Shift Length, and User Number.